# resultCallback for Unity Ads to only reward if video finished

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, ads

I recently added unity ads to a working game I had, and i want to figure out how to use the rewarded videos ad placements to make sure I only give the reward when the video is not skipped.
I already have unity ads working, and here is my code:

```
private static bool PlayUnityVideoAd()
{
    string adString = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UnityAds"+adName);
    if (Advertisement.isReady (adString)) {
        Advertisement.Show (adString, new ShowOptions {
            pause = true,
            resultCallback = result => {
                Debug.Log (result.ToString ())
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What do I need to change to have the function only return true if `ShowOptions.resultCallback` is set to Finished?
I tried to replace the `Debug.Log` line with a line to return a value from a switch, but it crashed unity.
I also have a feeling that `Advertisement.isShowing` might be needed to make sure to wait for the end of the video, but I don't know how to implement it.
So, the results I want are:
Finished => `return true;`
Failed => `return false;`
Skipped => `return false;`

Notes:
I am using `PlayerPrefs` to store the IDs for the different ad placement (`adString`).
This is part of a cascade with multiple ad networks, which is why i want it to return true or false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your answer is wrong, as the resultBool variable will be updated asynchronous, the "return resultBool" statement will always return true in your case if an Ad is available, not that the player finished the video.

A good implementation is to work with callbacks, a static you created somewhere, or even a dynamic event you would give in parameters.

It would be something like:

```
private static void PlayUnityVideoAd(Callback<bool> onVideoPlayed)
{
    string adString = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UnityAds" + adName);
    if (Advertisement.isReady (adString)) {
     Advertisement.Show (adString, new ShowOptions {
            pause = true,
            resultCallback = result => {
                switch(result)
                {
                case (ShowResult.Finished):
                    onVideoPlayed(true);
                    break;
                case (ShowResult.Failed):
                    onVideoPlayed(false);
                    break;
                case(ShowResult.Skipped):
                    onVideoPlayed(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    onVideoPlayed(false);
}
```

Just keep it mind that you may need to update your code workflow in order to keeping your original behavior, and working asynchronously. So intead of doing something like this:

```
void MyCodeWorkflow()
{
   //Doing somehing...
   bool result = PlayUnityVideoAd();
   if (result)
   {
     //Something
   }
   else
   {
     //Something else
   }
}
```

It would be:

```
public delegate void Callback<T>(T value);

void MyCodeWorkflow()
{
   //Doing somehing...
   PlayUnityVideoAd(delegate(bool result)
   {
     if (result)
     {
       //Something
     }
     else
     {
       //Something else
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering why it was saying that none of the videos where skipped when the UnityAds website said otherwise.

Comment: Juste updated the answer with some implementation précision.